# Как создать AlertDialog и добавить в него два EditText, кнопки Ок и Отмена?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, alert, android-alertdialog

Я хочу создать AlertDialog и добавить в него два EditText, кнопки Ок и Отмена. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Напишите текст: "
        android:textAppearance="?"
        androidd:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   
    </LinearLayout>
```

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    final Context context = this;
    private Button button;
    private TextView final_text;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Инициализируем элементы:
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prompt_button);
        final_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.final_text);

        //Добавляем слушателя нажатий по кнопке Button:
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                //Получаем вид с файла prompt.xml, который применим для диалогового 
    окна:
                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompt, null);

                //Создаем AlertDialog
                AlertDialog.Builder mDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                //Настраиваем prompt.xml для нашего AlertDialog:
                mDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

                //Настраиваем отображение поля для ввода текста в открытом диалоге:
                final EditText userInput = (EditText) 
                promptsView.findViewById(R.id.input_text);

                //Настраиваем сообщение в диалоговом окне:
            mDialogBuilder
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    //Вводим текст и отображаем в строке ввода на основном экране:
                        final_text.setText(userInput.getText());
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Отмена",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                 //Создаем AlertDialog:
                 AlertDialog alertDialog = mDialogBuilder.create();

                //и отображаем его:
                alertDialog.show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: И где тут EditText?

Comment: @edcft обновил )

Comment: Это конечно хорошо, что вы умеете [копировать](http://learn-android.ru/news/realizacija_vvoda_teksta_v_alert_dialog/2015-05-14-106.html), но вопервых мне нужно 2 EditText, а во вторых я читал эту статью но не очень понял эти манипуляции с xml файлами. Вы можете как-то объяснить? )

Comment: а что собственно вам непонятно? напишите разметку с двумя EditText в xml файле и работайте с ними в коде?

Comment: Спасибо, тут разобрался) Скажите, а вы не знаете как сделать так чтобы края этого алерта были закругленными?

Comment: @edcft https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161448/how-to-make-layout-with-rounded-corners

как-то так)

Comment: @edcft отметьте мой ответ - если он вам помог)

Comment: я отметил ваш ответ и + поставил. Спасибо за помощь)